# Ruby with Sinatra not loading when adding SendGrid or Mandrill

Tags: ruby, localhost, sinatra, require, sendgrid-ruby

I'm building a basic Ruby app with Sinatra and SendGrid.

When I try and run the file `ruby app.rb` the site does not load. When I remove `require 'sendgrid-ruby'` the app loads. Code below.

`app.rb`

```
require "sendgrid-ruby"
require "sinatra"
set :app_file, __FILE__

get '/' do
  puts "hi"
end
```

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'
```

Any help? I don't have a config.ru or anything else at this point. No error logging. It just hangs at waiting for LocalHost.

```
== Sinatra (v1.4.7) has taken the stage on 4567
for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

Ruby version: `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]`

EDIT:
Previously, I had `require "sinatra"` first and I didn't have `set :app_file, __FILE__` in there at all.

Comment: Is this the exact app that you're having difficulties with? Or is this just a very simplified example?

Comment: This is a very simplified example. Started a new test app to see if I would get the same behavior which I unfortunately did. And this is that code.

Comment: hmm then `puts "hi"` wouldn't show anything to the browser but that's not the real problem right? Can't reproduce your problem with `ruby 2.2.3p173`, `sinatra 1.4.7` and `thin 1.6.4`..

Comment: This is so odd. Really not sure what's happening. Thanks for taking the time cozy.